# How to get the events for the given list of zipcodes?

Tags: django, python-2.7, django-models

Hi I am having list of zipcodes

```
zipcodes = ['1234', '2132', '12312', '123123', '12317']
```

I have created an Event model as following:

```
class Event(models.Model):
 title = models.CharField(max_length=40)
 description = models.CharFi
 address = models.TextField(max_length=350, null=True, blank=True)
 city = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True, null=True)
 state = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True, null=False)
 province = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True, null=False)
 zipcode = models.CharField(max_length=10, blank=True)
```

Now for the given list of zipcodes I need to get all the event objects.How to write query in django for this?

Answer (score 2):

Use [`in`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/ref/models/querysets/#in):

```
zipcodes = ['1234', '2132', '12312', '123123', '12317']
Event.objects.filter(zipcode__in=zipcodes)
```